# How to get the right variable referenced

Tags: python

In the code below I am trying to get the second 'while' statement (while digit_check) to receive the new date from the earlier while_count statement.  But it seems to be picking up the original assignment for the user_date variable from the first assignment line.

How can I get the new variable assignment to pass to the second while statement?

Thanks much

```
def main():

    user_date = raw_input("Enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy and press 'Enter'  ")
    count = len(user_date)
    digit = ''
    digit_check = ''

    while count != 10:
        user_date = raw_input('try again  ')
        count = len(user_date)

    if user_date[0].isdigit() and user_date[1].isdigit() and user_date[3].isdigit()  \
       and user_date[4].isdigit() and user_date[6].isdigit() and user_date[7].isdigit() \
       and user_date[8].isdigit() and user_date[9].isdigit() and user_date[2] == '/' \
       and user_date[5] == '/':
           digit_check = True

    while digit_check != True :
       user_date = raw_input('Not right - try again')

    convert_date(user_date)

    print 'That date is ',convert_date(user_date) + ' ' + user_date[3] + user_date[4] + ',' + user_date[6:]

def convert_date(user_date):

    # Convert date to different format
    month = ''

    if user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '1':
        month = 'January'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '2':
        month = 'February'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '3':
        month = 'March'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '4':
        month = 'April'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '5':
        month = 'May'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '6':
        month = 'June'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '7':
        month = 'July'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '8':
        month = 'August'
    elif user_date[0] == '0' and user_date[1] == '9':
        month = 'September'
    elif user_date[0] == '1' and user_date[1] == '0':
        month = 'October'
    elif user_date[0] == '1' and user_date[1] == '1':
        month = 'November'
    elif user_date[0] == '1' and user_date[1] == '2':
        month = 'December'

    return month


main()
```

Comment: Well, that's probably because your giant if statement is failing? Note: you should rewrite your code.

Comment: @katrielalex, yea I should - that's why I'm trying to get some help.  Maybe you should try to be constructive and helpful!

Comment: I'm just saying, it will be easier for you to get help if you demonstrate that you have tried some of the obvious things. In this case, you should do a bit of debugging, probably with print statements, to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: @ katrielalex At this point I have spent several hours, yes hours, trying to figure this out and have approached it from every angle I could think of, given my very limited knowledge.  This is something totally new to me and I am trying to learn it. That's why I have posted it here.  I even did some searching in the archives here trying to come up with something before asking.  I'm very grateful to those who take the time to help with that.  Apparently that doesn't include you.  Just because someone asks a question doesn't mean they have made no effort.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you aren't recalculating digit_check here:

```
while digit_check != True :
   user_date = raw_input('Not right - try again')
```

This will just go into an infinite loop.

I'd suggest that instead of writing a huge function with many loops and lots of assignments, instead you refactor your code into smaller functions and use simpler logic. For example:

```
def getDate():
    while True:
        user_date = raw_input('Enter a date')
        if validate(user_date):
             return user_date
        else:
             print 'Error, try again.'

def validate(user_date):
    # etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the built-in library functions?

```
import re
import datetime

def getDate(msg="Enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy and press 'Enter': ", pat=re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})$')):
    while True:   # repeat until a valid date is entered
        s = raw_input(msg)            # get input
        match = pat.match(s.strip())  # match against regular expression
        if match:                     # match found?
            m,d,y = match.groups()
            try:
                # parse to date
                return datetime.date(int(y), int(m), int(d))
            except ValueError:
                # parsing failed (month 93 is invalid, etc)
                pass

def main():
    userDate = getDate()
    print('You entered {0}'.format(userDate.strftime('%B %d, %Y')))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't recomputing digit_check in that while loop, so it's failing forever, even though user_date is changing. Adding the if block inside the while loop after user_date = raw_input('Not right - try again') fixes it.

That being said, you should definitely make that check a separate function, especially since you'll now be calling it twice instead of once.